# Visual C++ Code Completion When Coding in C

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-c++

When I use Visual C++ for making C++ programs I see auto completion popup when I specify a namespace like `std::`

I want a similar feature for when I use this IDE to code in C, but since C has no namespaces, auto completion doesn't automatically popup as I type, unless I hit `Ctrl+J`.

It only pops up when I want to include files using the `#include` directive.

Is there a way to enable this feature for C, or does the IDE lack it completely?

Comment: No repro.  The auto-complete parser has no built-in knowledge of the `std` namespace.  Maybe you are mixing C++ and C files in your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try **Visual Assist X**. It can handle code auto-completion for `C` / `C++` / `C#` code.